# From QVariant to Integer and String

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtcore, qvariant

The user's entered `value` can be both: a string or an integer.

`QAbstractTableModel`'s `setData()` method always gets this `value` as `QtCore.QVariant`

**Question**:

How to implement `if/elif/else` inside of `setData()` to distinguish if the received `QVariant` is a string or an integer? (so a proper `QVariant` conversion method (such as .toString() or toInt()) is used)

P.s. Interesting that an attempt to convert `QVariant` toInt() results to a tuple such as: `(0, False)` or `(123, True)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[You can check against the type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#type):

```
if myVariant.type() == QVariant.Int:
    value = myVariant.toInt()
elif myVariant.type() == QVariant.QString:
    value = myVariant.toString()
```

Given that the form above is now obsolete, it is recommended [to check it this way](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#canConvert):

```
if myVariant.canConvert(QMetaType.Int):
    value = myVariant.toInt()
elif myVariant.canConvert(QMetaType.QString)
    value = myVariant.toString()
```